# What methodologies of increase perfomance ajax requests in ZF applications?

Tags: ajax, performance, zend-framework

I have a lot of ajax requests in my ZF application. And process of bootstraping takes a lot of time. What methodologies of increase perfomance ajax requests in ZF applications?
Maybe is there method to instance Zend Framework one time?

Comment: The two posts by MWOP discusses service API performance, but might as easily be applied to AJAX requests: [Exposing Service APIs via Zend Framework](http://mwop.net/blog/227-Exposing-Service-APIs-via-Zend-Framework), [Building RESTful Services with Zend Framework](http://mwop.net/blog/228-Building-RESTful-Services-with-Zend-Framework)

Comment: thanks, yes I had idea to forward ajax requests to scripts that takes only recources which need in this script.

Answer (score 1):

The bootstrapping process takes time, it's a fact, but you can use tools such as `Zend_Cache`to increase performance. For example, you can bootstrap you configuration file so you won't have to load it and parse after each request.

You can always store your php files called through Ajax on a different server or different path that doesn't rely on Zend Framework. If you separate your code from your entire application, then you won't have any overload for your Ajax request.

Be aware that if your Ajax requests need components such as Zend_Acl, Zend_Auth or any front controller plugins, you shouldn't separate your Ajax files from your application but keep them into your application. You can finally handle them using AjaxContext in your `_init()` actions.

To sum up:

- You need anything that Zend Framework provides (plugins, routing, acl, etc.) : **you should keep your ajax scripts inside your application.**
- You don't need all of that stuff: **make separate ajax scripts!**

Also, a good idea would be to overload the `run()` method in the bootstrap and instantiates only the resources needed in your ajax scripts.

Comment: yes, i cached my configs. I don't want separate bussines logic from ZF application. So I try phpdaemon. It works like nodejs based on libevent. It allows to bootstrap ZF appliaction one time. But I have some problems with it and it has bad support and documentation.

Comment: I decided to redevelope this part with nodeJS and Redis